# Spring OAuth2: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using the JdbcTokenStore and a hibernate database in parallel, and I am getting the following error when requesting an access token:

```
sparklr2 09:59:54.292 [DEBUG] ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter - Getting access token for: officialclient
sparklr2 09:59:54.292 [DEBUG] ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
sparklr2 09:59:54.292 [DEBUG] DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher - No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
sparklr2 09:59:54.308 [INFO] TokenEndpoint - Handling error: InternalAuthenticationServiceException, Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
sparklr2 09:59:54.448 [DEBUG] ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
sparklr2 09:59:54.448 [DEBUG] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Mär 16, 2016 9:59:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/organizer] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:565)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.java:47)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
    at my.base.package.controller.OfficialClientController.authenticate(OfficialClientController.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am requesting the token as follows:

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(tokenEndpoint);
        resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));
        resourceDetails.setId("resource");
        resourceDetails.setClientId("officialclient");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("officialclientsecret");
        resourceDetails.setUsername(username);
        resourceDetails.setPassword(password);

        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, context);
        return template.getAccessToken();
```

I enabled transaction management using `@EnableTransactionManagement` on my root configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import({WebMvcConfig.class, HibernateConfig.class, MethodSecurityConfig.class, OAuth2ServerConfig.class})
@ComponentScan("my.base.package")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

In `HibernateConfig`, I added the following code:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return txManager;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I am using a custom UserDetailsManager with the following `loadUserByUsername` method:

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(OrganizerUser.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        OrganizerUser user = (OrganizerUser) crit.uniqueResult();

        if(user == null) {
            trans.rollback();
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found!");
        }
        else {
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing an `@Transactional` on the custom `UserDetailsManager`.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11651632)

Comment: This was actually the complete solution to my problem

Comment: Can you accept your own answer in this case? Because someone in future may try to write new answer to your question.

Comment: I will, but I need to wait for two days before I can accept my own answer